# Encode or Transcode with ffmpeg and libx264 as fast as possible

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, performance

I'm trying to tune out ffmpeg to squeeze as much fps as possible from my server machines with lot of cores.

Sometimes expecially when there's also a scale (eg: shrinking down from 4k to full hd or from 1080p to 720p) not all cores are used. The behaviour is the same if I use -s:v 1280x720 or -filter:v "scale=-1:720"

I would like to have my machines use something as near as 90-98 % instead of the actual 20 % (on a 32 core machine using the threads 0 options make use of 22 cores but the usage is still 20%, same reasoning goes for 64 or 128 cores servers)

I also have a nvidia gpu on some machines that could be used for the resizing process maybe making the things more faster.

What kind of optimization can I think of to seriously burn out FPS?

tl;dr:

- max out the cpu usage
- use gpu if it can help and if it is possible (for example for the scale filter pass, it's just bicubic or linear resize cmon..)
- the files must be playable inside the well know h264 profiles like **main - 4.1**

I'm already using ultrafast and fixed bitrate, my aim is pure encoding speed and not the quality as you can see in my command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input.mov" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 3000k -profile:v main -level:v 4.1 -s:v 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -threads 0 "output.mov"
```

Comment: Do what the platforms do - segment, parallel encode, and rejoin

Comment: @Mulvya that could be an idea. Could you write or link me a good syntax / command line examples to do that ? I think is not something that you should do manually with -ss and -t right? Also because the trim command in ffmpeg under libx264 are not very precise and after the join the result could be terrible and stuttered. Thanks!

Comment: @user3450548, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133119/ffmpeg-splitting-large-files This might help you